# Wiping a hard drive before reinstallation

Tags: windows, linux, antivirus, operating-systems, trojan

A few years ago, I left a new laptop at a sketchy computer shop to downgrade the OS to Windows 7.  The experience was a disaster. My goal now is to install Cinnamon Linux on the laptop and remove Windows entirely.

I put the Kaspersky .iso on a blank disk and ran it from the boot menu (I believe this is called a rootkit scan).  It detected several problems, including trojans:

[image]
[image]

(images show several objects detected, including Trojan.Multi.GenAutorunTask.a, Trojan.VBS.AutoRun.ag, HEUR:Trojan.Script.Generic, Trojan.Multi.GenAutorunTaskFile.a, not-a-virus:HEUR:AdWare.Script.Extension.gen, and other less serious objects)

Kaspersky appears to have removed all of the objects successfully. Are there any further steps I should take before replacing the OS to be on the safe side, or will removing Windows be sufficient?

Comment: Why are you trying to clean it up before you wipe the hard drive and install Linux?

Comment: @user In case any malicious code might latch onto the new OS.

Comment: But you're searching for things that are on the hard drive, which will be wiped once you start installing Linux. If you really want to search for stuff you should do it after you wipe it, it will take you a lot less time to sift through it that way.

Comment: @user244277 assuming the drive is reformatted in the process. One assumes that is done in a fresh OS install, but it's important to note.

Comment: As long as you don't keep the windows partitions you're good. Note that if the laptop is **really old** you may need to get the 32-bit version of Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good part here is that you want to completely install a new OS. You don't need Windows to work or not be infected. In fact, you could fill the disk with random data prior to the Linux install in order to ensure nothing is left.

You mention that you are concerned about something there latching into the new OS. A virus installed on Windows affecting a clean Linux install on the same hardware would be extremely rare. Even for a clean Windows install it would be very strange to be affected, it is possible to store blobs in the BIOS that would then be loaded by Windows on install, or there might be a firmware virus installed. These are not things that would be even remotely likely to happen (probably not likely even if a foreign government wanted to spy on you), nor things that might be checked easily (or at all). Installing Cinnamon configured to wipe the existing contents would be enough to make that machine start from a clean state (other than getting new hardware).